# Cloud Foundry - can we auto scale app based on number of concurrent users

Tags: cloud-foundry

Cloud Foundry - can we auto scale app based on number of concurrent users

e.g would this be a custom metric and how does this work ?

Comment: which vendors cloud foundry are you using? VMWare, SAP, IBM? All of them have some differences and AFIK have somewhat different autoscaling capabilities.

Comment: VMWare is the flavour of Cf